# What ways exist with linq to compare if a case insensitive and culture using string exists within another

Tags: c#, linq

Comparing case insensitive strings with linq is quite easy, even to find out if a specific string is within another. The problems only start when it is also needed (as in my case) to differentate between ss and ß. As far as I have seen linq and string offer only 1 viable option there: Contains but the problem is the only contains overload that takes for example: StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase as parameter does not take string as parameter for the part that is searched within the "calling" string but instead takes ONLY a char value.

As it was asked: I'm using linq to gather info from a SQL database thus:

```
var results = (from c in myEntity.myTablename where 
(c.MyStringTextColumn.Contains(myStringTextToCompareWith)) 
select c.MyStringTextColumn).Distinct().ToList();
```

is how I'm comparing the strings originally but like I said the problem is this does not differentiate between ss and ß. Thus in the database there are different versions in regards to ss and ß stored, and I need to only find the "correct" one. Even though they are essentially the same one, an example would be strasse and straße (as names are stored in the database I couldn't use them in this example). If I type in strass I only want to find those strings that contain ss and not those with ß (thus straße should not be found)

So my question is: What options exist there?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring/15464440#15464440?

Comment: sadly not. I already tried the solutions there and linq says that it can't transform the indexof operation to something it knows.

Comment: So you're doing the comparison on the server?

Comment: I think OP is using linq to sql which doesn't support StringComparison usage

Comment: @YuliamChandra that is correct. I updated the question there. Didn't know that there is a huge difference between linq to sql and other versions to linq (only used it for getting data from sql sources so far)

Comment: yup, they are different, most of .net methods are not supported for linq to sql / linq to entities, so if in the database there is `ss` and in application you find by `ß`, the expected result would be returning `ss`?

Comment: @YuliamChandra no I want to find only the ß then if I search for that in the database (the problem is that ß and ss are treated as equal in default linq). I expanded the post a bit to better define what I need

Comment: You might be out of luck: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882672%28v=vs.100%29.aspx - "Unsupported String methods in general: Culture-aware overloads"

Comment: @dbc would it be possible then via extensions? (thus if I do my own extensions)?

Comment: or differently even though it is not optimized at all that way. Is it possible to use linqtodb to get all data reagardless of ss and ß and then to use "normal" linq on the generated list to differentate between ss and ß ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make use of the `IndexOf` property, which returns a non-negative int if the substring is found (it returns the index of the first character if found, otherwise -1), and also takes a StringComparison argument.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You mean something like this?c.myStringText.IndexOf(myCompareToString, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))

Answer (score 0):

Linq to sql doesn't support culture / case sensitive comparison, but it will rely on the database collation and the column type.

> Queries do not account for SQL Server collations that might be in
>   effect on the server, and therefore will provide culture-sensitive,
>   case-insensitive comparisons by default. This behavior differs from
>   the default, case-sensitive semantics of the .NET Framework. -
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882672%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

One option that you probably have is creating a stored procedure to do the searching like.

```
create proc sp_TableName
    (@name as varchar(max)) -- notice the type is varchar, not nvarchar
as
    select * from TableName
    where 
        cast(ColumnName as varchar(max)) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
        like '%' + @name + '%'
```

And using `SqlQuery<T>` to get the result.

```
var db = ...; // the context

var param = new SqlParameter("name", "ß");
var results = db.Database.SqlQuery<TableModel>("exec sp_TableName @name", param)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Or you can just execute all the data first, so that you can do the comparing as linq to objects, not linq to sql.

```
var results = (from c in myEntity.myTablename.AsEnumerable() where 
    (c.MyStringTextColumn.Contains(myStringTextToCompareWith)) 
    select c.MyStringTextColumn).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: @Thomas, did you try this approach ?